# Stop Custom post type from being searched via URL

Tags: custom-post-types, urls, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I am developing a website in WordPress and I have used a custom post type for people to use. The custom post type only shows if the user is logged in and is the author of it, this shows on the profile page and nowhere else.

What I want to do is stop people being able to search for it in the address bar, for example..

http://www.website.co.uk/custom-post-type/post-1 - This will show the single version of this post, however I need it to redirect to the login page.

http://www.website.co.uk/custom-post-type/ - This shows an archive page of the custom post type, however I need this to redirect to the login page. I have solved this temporaroly with a 301 redirect, however if you have any other advice, I would appreciate it.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `template_redirect` hook to redirect your pages, like this:

```
function my_page_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;
    $object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    //this returns queried object. Check the conditions and redirect
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect');
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I have this code which I beleive should work, however it doesn't...

`function my_page_template_redirect(){
    if( $post->post_type == 'custom-post-type' )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/login/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );`

The way I think this should work is, if the post is of a custom-post-type then redirect to the login page.

Comment: try $object->post_type

Comment: dump $object check how to get post_type name. $object returns object.

Comment: Good news, I have currently just managed to get the archive page of the custom post type to redirect which is half the battle using the following code... (Please excuse the formatting of the code, I haven't got the hang of posting properly)

`function toolkits_redirect() {
    $posttype = 'toolkits';
    if (is_post_type_archive($posttype)) {
  wp_redirect( home_url( '/agency-login/' ) );
  exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'toolkits_redirect');`

Comment: My second solution for redirecting the single template of the post, so people cant search for...

http://www.website.co.uk/custom-post-type/post-1

I used the `single_template` in order to give my custom post type a different single template then I placed a header redirect in that template to redirect to the desired page. Thank you for the help!! If you need the code I shall pop it on.